# How to request multiple API data to convert into json and do stuff to match the separate json files

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch

So I have a 2 API links that i want to get some data from 
https://some_url/users and https://some_url/posts.

I want to match some data from /users with /posts but how do i fetch from both at the same time

I know that if I wanted to just fetch say from /users, I would go

```
   fetch('https://some_url/users')
   .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
   })
   .then(function(Data_users){

       do stuff to Data_users

   }
```

But I want to do stuff to both the the /users data and /posts data at the same time so I want to fetch from both /users and /posts and manipulate them here like this

```
   .then(function(Data_users, Data_posts){

       do stuff to Data_users and Data_posts

   }
```

How would I do this? Would I need a promise?

Apologies if I explained it really badly, I'm very new to javascript.

Comment: use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) `Promise.all([fetch1, fecth2]).then(([Data_users, Data_posts])=> {....})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this with `Promise.all()`

```
var userPromise = fetch('https://some_url/users').then(response => response.json());
var postPromise = fetch('https://some_url/posts').then(response => response.json());

Promise.all([userPromise, postPromise]).then(([Data_users, Data_posts]) => {
    ...
});
```

The brackets around the two variables in the last function are required, because `Promise.all` calls the function with an array. With the brackets, we can decompose the array into two distinct variables.
Without brackets, the following code would be required:

```
....then((values) => {
    var Data_users = values[0];
    var Data_posts = values[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One question though, do I need the [ ] brackets, if not what exactly do they do

Comment: I added some explanation for the brackets to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise.all, it will return both the results in an array, then you can use to compare the results.

We can use async await here, using async await will make the code more readable and structured.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const run = async () => {
    const [users_res, posts_res] = await 
          Promise.all([fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'),  
                       fetch('https://reqres.in//api/users/2')]);
    console.log(users_res, posts_res);
    // we can compare users_res and posts_res here.
}

run()
```